# Trying to install WhiteSur

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gtk

I was trying to install WhiteSur theme on my Ubuntu 18.04

I did `./install.sh` in terminal after downloading theme pack

it shows the following error:

[image]

what's wrong here?

Comment: Have you installed the `libglib2.0-dev` and `libxml2-utils` from source as described in [the installation notes](https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme)? If so, can you [edit] your question to include all of the steps that you’ve followed? This may make it easier to identify the issue and offer a solution 

Comment: Your picture of the text shows a couple of things that you could try. Reread the text carefullyPlease read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting ..Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Add command "sudo" in start line